# column vector without using \bmatrix?

Tags: math-mode, align, matrices

How can I write a colomn vector like following without using `\bmatrix`? (no `\usepackage{amsmath}`)

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `amsmath` needed, using `\left[...\right]` and an `array` environment in between, just 'ordinary' math - content from LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
$y = \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{m} 
    \end{array} \right]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note: The lines are not displayed correctly, this is a PDF viewer issue, not a LaTeX issue!

Answer (score 1):

One can make a stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
y = \bracketVectorstack{x_1 x_2 \abovebaseline[-3pt]{\vdots} x_m}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: couldn't get this to work.

Comment: @alexlomba87 It can only be one of two things...either you don't have `stackengine` installed or you have an outdated version.  In either case, you can get the latest file versions at https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine